# regex to match quotes and a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying in javascript, to create a regex to replace quotes and a comma, and replace the comma with a blank.

For example

`x = "$1,200.00"    =>   "$1200.00"`

`x.replace(/^"[,]"+/g, "");`

Comment: your example data doesn't have any quotes

Comment: Change the replace to `x.replace(/[,"]/g, "");` which will remove any `,` and `"` (if that really is what you want?).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simple?

```
var res = x.replace(",", "");
```

Comment: This is a pretty simple answer,but did he actually need this answer?

Comment: If he was added this question - "Why not"?